# How to set encoding to "UTF8 without bom" in Azure Blob output dataset

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm currently producing daily .json output with Azure Data Factory. My partners need the encoding to be in UTF8 but without BOM characters.

Is there anyway to do that in the configuration file in AzureDataFactory ?
I found out the encodingName property :

```
        "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "prod-file-{date}.json",
        "folderPath": "folder",
        "format": {
            "type": "JsonFormat",
            "encodingName":""
        },
```

but the list of matchings [encodingName parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) doesn't seems to correspond to my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In json file format default value for encoding name is UTF-8

Comment: If you have the physical config file and can upload it, then you can change it in NotePad++ via its Encoding Menu.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me setting the encoding to UTF-8 and having file format text created UTF-8 BOM files.

Leaving the encoding empty used the apparent default of UTF-8 without BOM.

Does not make sense, but hope it works with JSON as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you asked they didn't have that option. But now there is a `UTF-8 without BOM` option in the Json dataset properties.

Go to your Json Dataset and set the `Encoding` with `UTF-8 without BOM` as below:

[image]